# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word reference in Visual Studio 2015 and MS Office 2016

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2015, ms-word, office-interop

I have Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 and office 2010, a git CV system, and an autobuild system based on TeamCity Enterprise. There is a project that contain references to "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word".

On a new workplace I have installed VS 2015 (update 1) and MS Office 2016. This gave an issue `type or namespace 'Office' not found in Microsoft`.
I then deleted old references and add new references "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" and "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library".

Now, in new Visual Studio 2015 project compiles OK. But the `.csproj-file` that has been changed is not compiling on other programmers computers, that have VS 2012 or VS 2013.

Is there a way to combine both references for different Office versions?
Alternatively, how can I configure this moment so that it would work fine on all workplaces? Can I just copy old .dll (from Office 2010) to a my computer and add it to project as outer .dll? Or is it bad idea?

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you asking about the csproj-file or the Word references? Those are two different things. A project compiled on with newer version of Visual Studio isn't going to work in older versions. If you work in a team then everyone in the team should use the same system / the system required for an individual project.

Answer (score 0):

Always program against the *oldest* version of Word (any Office program) that your solution needs to support. Something compiled against version 2016 isn't going to run against 2010 and you might end up using functionality not available in the older version.

It is possible to *embed* the interop information in your solution, making it PIA version independent (look up "embed interop types" - you need to activate that option for the PIA reference), but the problem with using unsupported functionality remains!